# Common attribute Type for Integer and String in java

Tags: java, hibernate

I have created a method which has arument as Integer to fetch the DB record from Db using hibernate. Now i have string type argument for the same scenario. Can i change that method signature to Serializable to support Integer and String. Are there any issues if I have Serializable as the method argument.?

```
public Object get(final Class classObject, final Serializable id)
            throws PersistenceException {
        LOGGER.debug(LOG_PREFIX + "get::Begin");
        Object obj = this.runInSession(new PersistentUnitOfWork() {
            public Object run() throws PersistenceException {
                return getPersistenceContext().get(classObject, id);
            }
        });
        LOGGER.debug(LOG_PREFIX + "get::End");
        return obj;
    }
```

any issue comes due to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Hibernate API, the get method of the session supports an id of type serializable. I do not expect any issue coming with this, if this is officially supported by the API

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#get(java.lang.Class,java.io.Serializable

What sense would it have to have such an API, if you could not use it?